# How to get specific files Filespath in c#

Tags: c#

There is big hierarchy of folders which contains around 1million csv files. This csv contain many types of csv like  value, tag, invoices ,report and I want to move them to specific location.
But I want to move all files except value csv files. And this million files I am moving in batch according to our need by executing exe.

```
enter code here



static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string source = "C:\\Desktop\\Source1";
        string destination = "D:\\3";
        var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Skip(0).Take(i);
        int cnt = 0;
       foreach (string txt in filePaths)
        {
            cnt++;
            if(!txt.Contains("Value"))
            {
                File.Move(destination,source);

            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Show us what you've tried first, then we can help you figure out why it's not working

Comment: int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string source = "C:\\Users\\KARTIK\\Desktop\\Source1";
string destination = "C:\\Users\\KARTIK\\Desktop\\Source1\\3";
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Skip(0).Take(i);
int cnt = 0;
foreach (string txt in filePaths)
    {
        cnt++;
                if(!txt.Contains("Value"))
                {
                    File.Move(destination,source);

                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        
        }

Comment: @user13573775 Do not add the source code you have as a comment, [edit] your question to add it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `File.Move(destination,source)` is only moving the top-level folders and you're moving them in the wrong direction
- When moving/copying files you always need to ensure the parent directory of the destination exists. Otherwise you'll get an exception

Below is an example of how you can move the files. Note that I've added `*.csv` to the file pattern in case you're only interested in CSV files, which it sounds like. And case-insensitive string comparison in case your file names are not so consistent.

```
int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string source = "C:\\Desktop\\Source1";
string destination = "D:\\3";
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Skip(0).Take(i);

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
    if(!file.Name.Contains("value", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var sourceRelativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(source, file.FullName);
        var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destination, sourceRelativePath);
        var destinationFile = new FileInfo(destinationFilePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Moving \"{0}\" to \"{1}\"", file.FullName, destinationFile.FullName);
        destinationFile.Directory.Create(); // Make sure the directory for the destination file exists
        file.MoveTo(destinationFile.FullName, overwrite: true);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I have 4 types of csv files based on we have named them like csv file with name starting value, invoices, tag ,and report. I only want to move files except value csv for further processing is there any way?

Comment: @user13573775 I don't understand. Is the example in my answer not doing what you want? If not, then what is wrong?

Comment: Code you provided giving me all csv files. I do not want all csv files. As I described earlier my folder contains 4 types of csv files like value01.csv,tag002.csv,report00.csv and i want to retrieve every file except csv file having name value in the name.

Comment: @user13573775 ok, to be fair you never mentioned the format of the file names. I've updated the code to use `.Contains("value",...` instead of `.EndsWith("value.csv",...`. Does that work for you?